# We was gonna have some fun

Tags: verbs, dialects, verb-agreement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“You was trouble”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55404/you-was-trouble)

In the movie "[Thelma & Louise](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103074/)", Thelma says:

> You said we **was** gonna have some fun, so let's have some!

So my question is why does she say "was" instead of "were"? Is it meant to indicate something like the woman is illiterate?
And what would people think of me if I talked like that?

Comment: Related: [“You was trouble”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55404/you-was-trouble)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the verb is deliberately conjugated wrong, to give the remark a *backwoods* tone or feel.

> **backwoods** (adj): unsophisticated; uncouth

Comment: I would say it was conjugated **correctly** for the dialect in which it occurs.

Comment: @BarrieEngland: Okay... interesting viewpoint.  Correctness, like beauty, is in the eye of the beholder. :^)

Comment: No, it's in the mouth of the speaker!

Comment: Or ears of the listener?  Eyes of the reader?

Comment: Or the mind of the linguist.

Comment: _"Backwoods"_ is a perfect evocation of the stereotype of poor, uncouth, rural, illiterate speech in American culture. Linguists talk about rather a [different version of "Correctness"](http://people.ucsc.edu/~pullum/MLA2004.pdf).